# Kafka Streams Processors are not initialized

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I execute a script which creates 10 Kafka Streams Application instances:.

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors1 VectorSink1 VectorSink2 VectorSourceNodeName1 VectorProcessorName1 StateStoreName1 sk1-client sk1-group sk1-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors2 VectorSink3 VectorSink4 VectorSourceNodeName2 VectorProcessorName2 StateStoreName2 sk2-client sk2-group sk2-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors3 VectorSink5 VectorSink6 VectorSourceNodeName3 VectorProcessorName3 StateStoreName3 sk3-client sk3-group sk3-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors4 VectorSink7 VectorSink8 VectorSourceNodeName4 VectorProcessorName4 StateStoreName4 sk4-client sk4-group sk4-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors5 VectorSink9 VectorSink10 VectorSourceNodeName5 VectorProcessorName5 StateStoreName5 sk5-client sk5-group sk5-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors6 VectorSink11 VectorSink12 VectorSourceNodeName6 VectorProcessorName6 StateStoreName6 sk6-client sk6-group sk6-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors7 VectorSink13 VectorSink14 VectorSourceNodeName7 VectorProcessorName7 StateStoreName7 sk7-client sk7-group sk7-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors8 VectorSink15 VectorSink16 VectorSourceNodeName8 VectorProcessorName8 StateStoreName8 sk8-client sk8-group sk8-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors9 VectorSink17 VectorSink18 VectorSourceNodeName9 VectorProcessorName9 StateStoreName9 sk9-client sk9-group sk9-appid"  &
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SiteApplication" -Dexec.args="Vectors10 VectorSink19 VectorSink20 VectorSourceNodeName10 VectorProcessorName10 StateStoreName10 sk10-client sk10-group sk10-appid"  &
```

I found out with the help of the logger that the `init` method of the processor is not called to some of the application instances and they are not initialized.

My topology of the streams application is:

```
toplogy.addSource(vectorSourceNodeName, stringDeserializer, integerDeserializer, args[0])
        .addProcessor(vectorProcessorName,
                      ()->new SiteProcessor(vectorSink1, vectorSink2),
                      vectorSourceNodeName)
        .addSink(vectorSink1,"IncreaseOfC", stringSerializer, byteArraySerializer, vectorProcessorName)
        .addSink(vectorSink2, "Messages", stringSerializer, byteArraySerializer1, vectorProcessorName);
```

I cannot tell why it not initializing and how to debug.

I do not use state stores.

(The problems occurred after a bug in my code that would stick in a while loop and I executed the command `pkill -u user` in order for the execution to stop but I fixed the bug. Is there a problem with the installation of kafka? How should I find out? )

**Edit:**
I found out by logger that for those Applications whose Processors **are initialized** it is logged that:

```
INFO  AbstractCoordinator:677 - [Consumer clientId=sk5-client-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=sk5-appid] Discovered group coordinator myserver:6667 (id: 2147482646 rack: null)

INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:472 - [Consumer clientId=sk5-client-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=sk5-appid] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
 INFO  StreamThread:209 - stream-thread [sk5-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PARTITIONS_REVOKED
 INFO  KafkaStreams:261 - stream-client [sk5-client] State transition from RUNNING to REBALANCING
 INFO  StreamThread:320 - stream-thread [sk5-client-StreamThread-1] partition revocation took 1 ms.
    suspended active tasks: []
    suspended standby tasks: []

StreamsPartitionAssignor:579 - stream-thread [sk5-client-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}.
INFO  AbstractCoordinator:473 - [Consumer clientId=sk5-client-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=sk5-appid] Successfully joined group with generation 1
INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:280 - [Consumer clientId=sk5-client-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=sk5-appid] Setting newly assigned partitions [Vectors5-0]
INFO  StreamThread:209 - stream-thread [sk5-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED
INFO  StreamThread:280 - stream-thread [sk5-client-StreamThread-1] partition assignment took 23 ms.
    current active tasks: [0_0]
    current standby tasks: []
    previous active tasks: []
 INFO  StreamThread:209 - stream-thread [sk5-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
INFO  KafkaStreams:261 - stream-client [sk5-client] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
```

For those Applications whose Processors **are not initialized** it is logged that `State transition from CREATED to RUNNING` only and no rebalancing takes place.

As the logger suggests those  stream applications whose processors are not initiallized cannot discover group coordinator. Is it a problem that I have to report to the administrator of the cluster that runs apache kafka or is it a bug in my code that I have to search for? Thanks in advance.